# How do I find the solutions to $GCD(a,b) = au + bv$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Our teacher says there is a theorem such that $GCD(a,b) = au + bv$ where $u,v\in \mathbb Z$
I'm wondering how I would solve such an equation. For example:

How would I go about solving $GCD(821,123) = 821u + 123v$ or $GCD(231,1820) = 1820u + 231v$?
The first step is obviously use Euclid's Algorithm to get the $GCD$ but after that how do I solve it?

Here is the formula as she stated it:

[image]

Comment: Once you have one solution you have all solutions by substitution. Is this what you meant?

Comment: About the formula in the title. That was just given to us in our class. I can post a screen shot from the lecture slides if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the so-called [extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). I should mention that one important application of this algorithm is computing modular inverses. Given an integer $n$ and an integer $a$ relatively prime to $n$, you can use the extended Euclidean algorithm to find $b$ such that $ab \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ (that is, $n|ab-1$) – can you see how? (Use the fact that $(a,n)=1$.)

Answer (score 3):

Once you have the GCD using Euclid's algorithm you are done, you only have to "go backwards". Let me clear that with an example.

Let's use $24$ and $136$.

Now:

$136 = 24(5) + 16$

$24 = 16(1)+8$

$16 = 8(2)$

So the $GCD(24,136) = 8$
Going "backwards" we have:
$8 = 24 - 16(1) = 24 - ( 136 - 24(5)) = 24(6) + 136(-1)$
Check Bezout's identity.